# ListPlot3D with small (but acceptable) precision

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

Consider the following minimal example:

```
delta = 0.00001;
data = Block[{x = RandomReal[], y = RandomReal[]},
    Table[{x + RandomReal[] delta, y + RandomReal[] delta, RandomInteger[100]},
        {i, 1, 100}]];

ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

The plot doesn't shows anything.

If I set `delta = 0.1`, it already shows.

Does anyone know how do I plot a dataset with a small distance between max and min?

Edit:

```
$Version
```

> 9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)

Answer (score 2):

Must be a version issue:

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014)"

```
SeedRandom[10];
delta = 0.00001;
data = Block[{
    x = RandomReal[],
    y = RandomReal[]},
   Table[{
     x + RandomReal[] delta,
     y + RandomReal[] delta,
     RandomInteger[100]},
    {i, 1, 100}]];

ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> {Min[data], Max[data]}]
```